# How can I say someone is precious person in Korean?

Tags: hanja

Is it correct if I call someone 소중인 ? Does that make any sense in Korean?

소중 - precious
인 - person

Answer (score 1):

You cannot combine any things like that. And 귀인 is idiomatic.

Answer (score 1):

If someone is your lover: 소중한 사람

귀인 is more like VIP i think.